# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'twint'

Tags: module, jupyter, modulenotfounderror, named

I installed twint with cmd in Python 3.7 but error in jupyter
ModuleNotFoundError: Gives no module named 'twint'.

Comment: You don't say what 'cmd' you used? Therefore I specifically cannot give you the version to use; however,  it sounds like where you installed and where Jupyter runs from are not the same places. The easiest solution, run inside a new cell in Jupyter `%pip install ... ` or `%conda install ...`. Use whatever most matches what you tried already and replace the `...` with your package name. That will use the magic command `pip` or `conda` command inside your Jupyter and insure installation to where the environment is that backs your Jupyter.

Comment: See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more information about the modern `%pip install` and `%conda install` commands that make it easier in Jupyter now.